# Installing gems fails in deployment - AWS Elastic Beanstalk

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-web-services, deployment, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

The native gems are not installing while I try to deploy the app in AWS Elastic Beanstalk(EB) environment.

**eb-activity.log**

```
  Don't run Bundler as root. Bundler can ask for sudo if it is needed, and
  installing your bundle as root will break this application for all non-root
  users on this machine.
  Warning: the running version of Bundler is older than the version that created the lockfile. We suggest you upgrade to the latest version of Bundler by running `gem install bundler`.
  fatal: Not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git
  fatal: Not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git
  Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/
  Fetching version metadata from https://rubygems.org/
  Fetching dependency metadata from https://rubygems.org/
  Resolving dependencies...
  Installing rake 11.2.2
  Installing i18n 0.7.0
  Using json 1.8.3
  Installing minitest 5.9.0
  Installing thread_safe 0.3.5
  Installing builder 3.2.2
  Installing erubis 2.7.0
  Installing mini_portile2 2.1.0
  Installing pkg-config 1.1.7
  Installing rack 1.6.4
  Installing mime-types-data 3.2016.0521
  Installing arel 6.0.3
  Installing jmespath 1.3.1
  Installing bcrypt 3.1.11 with native extensions

  Gem::Ext::BuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

      current directory: /var/app/ondeck/gems/bundle/gems/bcrypt-3.1.11/ext/mri
  /opt/rubies/ruby-2.3.1/bin/ruby -r ./siteconf20160916-26394-19gpiil.rb extconf.rb
  Cannot allocate memory - /opt/rubies/ruby-2.3.1/bin/ruby -r ./siteconf20160916-26394-19gpiil.rb extconf.rb 2>&1

  Gem files will remain installed in /var/app/ondeck/gems/bundle/gems/bcrypt-3.1.11 for inspection.
  Results logged to /var/app/ondeck/gems/bundle/extensions/x86_64-linux/2.3.0-static/bcrypt-3.1.11/gem_make.out
  Using bundler 1.12.1
  Installing rubyzip 1.2.0
  Installing coderay 1.1.1
  Installing coffee-script-source 1.10.0
  Installing execjs 2.7.0
  Installing thor 0.18.1
  Installing concurrent-ruby 1.0.2
  Installing orm_adapter 0.5.0
  Installing unf_ext 0.0.7.2 with native extensions

  Gem::Ext::BuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

      current directory: /var/app/ondeck/gems/bundle/gems/unf_ext-0.0.7.2/ext/unf_ext
  /opt/rubies/ruby-2.3.1/bin/ruby -r ./siteconf20160916-26394-1kl25wy.rb extconf.rb
  Cannot allocate memory - /opt/rubies/ruby-2.3.1/bin/ruby -r ./siteconf20160916-26394-1kl25wy.rb extconf.rb 2>&1

  Gem files will remain installed in /var/app/ondeck/gems/bundle/gems/unf_ext-0.0.7.2 for inspection.
  Results logged to /var/app/ondeck/gems/bundle/extensions/x86_64-linux/2.3.0-static/unf_ext-0.0.7.2/gem_make.out
  Installing hashie 3.4.4
  Installing htmlentities 4.3.4
  Installing multi_xml 0.5.5
  Installing multi_json 1.12.1
  Installing jwt 1.5.4
  Installing method_source 0.8.2
  Installing mimemagic 0.3.0
  Installing mqtt 0.4.0
  Installing netrc 0.11.0
  Installing pg 0.18.4 with native extensions

  Gem::Ext::BuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

      current directory: /var/app/ondeck/gems/bundle/gems/pg-0.18.4/ext
  /opt/rubies/ruby-2.3.1/bin/ruby -r ./siteconf20160916-26394-4s0qe7.rb extconf.rb
  Cannot allocate memory - /opt/rubies/ruby-2.3.1/bin/ruby -r ./siteconf20160916-26394-4s0qe7.rb extconf.rb 2>&1

  Gem files will remain installed in /var/app/ondeck/gems/bundle/gems/pg-0.18.4 for inspection.
  Results logged to /var/app/ondeck/gems/bundle/extensions/x86_64-linux/2.3.0-static/pg-0.18.4/gem_make.out
  Installing slop 3.6.0
  Installing rack-cors 0.4.0
  Installing sass 3.4.22
  Installing tilt 2.0.5
  Installing turbolinks-source 5.0.0
  Installing will_paginate 3.1.0
  Installing apipie-rails 0.3.6
  Installing rdoc 4.2.2
  Installing tzinfo 1.2.2
  Installing nokogiri 1.6.8 with native extensions

  Gem::Ext::BuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

      current directory: /var/app/ondeck/gems/bundle/gems/nokogiri-1.6.8/ext/nokogiri
  /opt/rubies/ruby-2.3.1/bin/ruby -r ./siteconf20160916-26394-13djrm9.rb extconf.rb
  Cannot allocate memory - /opt/rubies/ruby-2.3.1/bin/ruby -r ./siteconf20160916-26394-13djrm9.rb extconf.rb 2>&1

  Gem files will remain installed in /var/app/ondeck/gems/bundle/gems/nokogiri-1.6.8 for inspection.
  Results logged to /var/app/ondeck/gems/bundle/extensions/x86_64-linux/2.3.0-static/nokogiri-1.6.8/gem_make.out
  Installing rack-test 0.6.3
  Installing warden 1.2.6
  Installing mime-types 3.1
  Installing aws-sdk-core 2.6.1
  An error occurred while installing bcrypt (3.1.11), and Bundler cannot continue.
  Make sure that `gem install bcrypt -v '3.1.11'` succeeds before bundling. (Executor::NonZeroExitStatus)
```

I tried the following:

1. updating bundler using `gem update bundler` command in EB `/var/app/current` directory and the is no improvements.
2. Removing `gemfile.lock` and `bundle install` in local and deployed updated `gemfile.lock`.

The same above error occurs everytime.

**I am using Rails `4.2.4` with ruby `2.3` version.**

Please help me. Thanks.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I finally solved the issue by caching the gem.

I ran `bundle package` in local and it creates the gem caches in the `vendor/cache` directory.

Now, while deploying in AWS with those cached gems it tries to use the cached gem instead of installing it. I don't know whether it is a good practice but, it solved my issue.

I got this solution from the AWS blog: [Locally Packaging Gem Dependencies for Ruby Applications in Elastic Beanstalk](http://blogs.aws.amazon.com/application-management/post/Tx2XVRWSS4E971S/Locally-Packaging-Gem-Dependencies-for-Ruby-Applications-in-Elastic-Beanstalk)

**Edit #1:** Adding @sybind's comment in answer

`bundle package --all` will include `all :git references`

If there is any better solution please let me know.

Comment: bundle package --all will include all :git references

Comment: I get `Some gems seem to be missing from your vendor/cache directory.
Could not find nokogiri-1.12.4 in any of the sources` when I do bundle package.
I can see `nokogiri-1.12.4-x86_64-darwin` in vendor/cache

Comment: Hi @ImranAhmad where you able to solve that issue ? I'm seeing the exact same message about not finding nokogiri.

Comment: @ImranAhmad Had you tried manually adding your nokogiri-1.12.4 under vendor/cache?
If not please try this command to add nokogiri in vendor/cache 
`bundle add --skip-install path/to/nokogiri-1.12.4-x86_64-darwin.gem`