# Rails deployment failed to install dependency gems - Elastic Beanstalk

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I'm trying to deploy a rails app in Elastic Beanstalk but I keep encountering this error: `Instance deployment failed to install dependency gems that you defined in 'Gemfile'`. I'm stuck and not sure how to resolve this?

Here's the log:

```
2022-02-05 20:57:40    INFO    Deploying new version to instance(s).
2022-02-05 20:57:48    ERROR   Instance deployment failed to install dependency gems that you defined in 'Gemfile'. For details, see 'eb-engine.log'. The deployment failed.
2022-02-05 20:57:48    ERROR   Instance deployment failed. For details, see 'eb-engine.log'.
2022-02-05 20:57:51    ERROR   [Instance: i-0fd0e5b3638cb7ab1] Command failed on instance. Return code: 1 Output: Engine execution has encountered an error..
2022-02-05 20:57:51    INFO    Command execution completed on all instances. Summary: [Successful: 0, Failed: 1].
2022-02-05 20:57:51    ERROR   Unsuccessful command execution on instance id(s) 'i-0fd0e5b3638cb7ab1'. Aborting the operation.
2022-02-05 20:57:51    ERROR   Failed to deploy application.
```

Update: Retrieved the logs and this is what I found

```
 An error occurred during execution of command [app-deploy] - [stage ruby application]. Stop running the command. Error: install dependencies in Ge
mfile failed with error Command /bin/sh -c bundle _2.3.6_ install --local failed with error exit status 7. Stderr:Don't run Bundler as root. Bundler can ask for sudo if it is needed
, and
installing your bundle as root will break this application for all non-root
users on this machine.
Could not find nokogiri-1.13.1-x86_64-linux in any of the sources
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Installing gems fails in deployment - AWS Elastic Beanstalk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39525129/installing-gems-fails-in-deployment-aws-elastic-beanstalk)

Comment: @dbugge It does not, unfortunately. I already checked vendor/cache and it has `nokogiri-1.13.1-x86_64-linux.gem`

Comment: I'm having the same issue with Nokogiri. Deployments are successful on my Webserver but not on my worker for some reason....both launches are identical.

Comment: @bkunzi01 were you able to find a solution?

Comment: Yes. I upgraded from a T2Micro to a T2Small.  Turns out it was an issue with available memory in the instance.