# Instance deployment failed to install dependency gems that you defined in 'Gemfile'. For details, see 'eb-engine.log'. The deployment failed

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I'm facing this issue while trying to deploy rails app via AWS Elastic-beanstalk cli.

Even I tried this solution [Installing gems fails in deployment - AWS Elastic Beanstalk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39525129/installing-gems-fails-in-deployment-aws-elastic-beanstalk) but NO LUCK.

Comment: Did you look at the eb-engine.log file? What was the error?

Answer (score 1):

I don't really know where you are in your deployment without specific error or log information. Please post more log info so we can better help you! If you don't have detailed logging, try setting it up using [these steps](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/eb3-logs.html)

Assuming your error is in the `eb-engine.log` file, you can try the following steps to troubleshoot the issue:

- Check the error message in the log file to see if it provides any clues about the cause of the error.
- Check the Elastic Beanstalk environment settings to ensure that all required settings are properly configured.
- Check the Ruby on Rails application code for any errors or issues that may be causing the error.

If necessary, try redeploying the application using the eb deploy command.